# Не работает ввод в input в modal

Tags: html, css, jquery, ios, bootstrap

Доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся проблемой, суть которой описываю ниже:

1. На сайт добавил платежную систему Яндекс.Касса.
2. На компьютере все проверил - работает хорошо.
3. А вот на мобильных браузерах (причем всех), происходит нечто невероятное: при правильном вводе номера карты автоматически перекидывает на поле ввода срока действия. И в этот момент экран начинает прыгать и клавиатура на телефоне перестает работать. Если нажать на клавиатуре "Готово", а затем вручную нажать на поле ввода - то все вводится нормально.

Форма оплаты реализована с помощью виджета, который встроен в модальное окно (bootstrap). Сам виджет подгружает в модальное окно iframe с самой формой.
Перепробовал все (и абсолютное позиционирование для разных контейнеров родительских, и встроить виджет просто на страницу - толку ноль, убил на это целый день :)).
Для лучше понимания прикрепляю GIF с самим процессом "оплаты".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего это не в форме дело, а в работе какого то скрипта, что-то мешает обработки клика. Пробуйте отключать сторонние скрипты, виджеты.

Comment: К сожалению, не помогло. Поочередно скрипты отключал - толку 0... :(

Comment: Причем я даже попробовал вообще все стили и скрипты убрать. И контент весь убрать, оставить только подключение платежки. В итоге все равно прыгает.